# Polymer dropdwon menu - window scroll is working always

Tags: drop-down-menu, polymer

I am using polymer dropdown menu but my window scrollbar is getting scroll always, I have tried using **allowOutsideScroll** attribute but my scrollbar is working when I open the select box. I don't want scrollbar when user opens the select box.

```
<paper-dropdown-menu
                  id="accountName"
                  horizontal-align="left"
                  class="custom"
                  label="Select By Account Name"
                  on-iron-select="getRebateName"
                  no-label-float="true">
                    <paper-listbox attr-for-selected="value" class="dropdown-content" selected="{{accountNameSelected}}">
                        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{accountsList}}">
                            <paper-item value="{{item.accountName}}">{{item.accountName}}</paper-item>
                        </template>
                    </paper-listbox>
                </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Comment: You say "window scrollbar", but do you mean the scrollbar on the expanded dropdown menu? A screenshot would be helpful (or a jsbin/fiddle/codepen).

Comment: @tony19 window scrollbar( the main body default scrollbar ) is working, I don't want it to work, I tried all the properties of dropdown menu

Comment: You can use something like`iron-overlay` to stop scrolling or you can also hide overflow of the page when drop-down is opened. I haven't seen any default solution from Polymer for this situation